# Graduated Symbology in QGIS 3.8.1

Tags: symbology

I have a state layer with counties outlined I've joined an .XLSX file on County_Name with populations.  Finally figured out how to do a graduated symbology but when I run it I get the highest symbols and the rest of the display is blank; I lose the outlines of all but the displayed symbols.
Does what I want in ArcGIS 10.6 and trying to replicate in QGIS 3.8.1.
It's probably something simple that I've just overlooked.
Not a GIS professional, just a dabbler.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my fault.  Thought I'd triple checked my data; wrong...
County_Names in joined .XLSX file had extra space at end of each name.
No successful join.
Fixed it and now it works!
Thanks for looking and sorry to bother you.

Dave

Comment: Please accept the answer that it is clear that you no longer look for a solution: Click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers